# Line breaks to Woocommerce attributes using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, line-breaks

I've been searching around different posts about how to do line breaks without using HTML. However none of them seems to be able to fix my issue.

I currently have a system setup using the Woocommerce attributes on different products. It looks like this on a

**Desktop computer:** 
[image: Desktop example]

I did this by using

```css
ul.custom-attributes li {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

which is great. However the code doesn't give the same result on mobile as it looks like this:

**Phone example:**

[image: Phone example]

Any idea how I can force the attributes to do a line break so that it will work on mobile as well.

Thank you very much.

-Daniel

Comment: try clear:both or share the html code

Comment: If you have a link where we can access this website online, it would much easier for us to give you a proper solution.

Comment: Website adress is: http://billigstewebhosting.dk/produkt-kategori/billig-webhotel/.

Comment: Thank you! Clear: both seems to have been the solution! It looks fairly good now.

Comment: Can you post an answer Lucky so I can set it as solved :) ?